# Что делать с текстами, в которых присутвуют пустые строки?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Всем привет! Заголовок запроса может быть не понятен, но я сейчас попробую объяснить. На сервере есть тексты, как эти:

```
Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне.

Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую...
```

Вот как видно тут, в этом тексте есть пустая строка. Если просто вывести этот текст на страницу то, все хорошо отобразиться. А если нужно его обрезать?

Если поместить такой текст в переменную, то получится вот так:

```
let description = 'Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне.

Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую...';
```

И тогда произойдет ошибка и текст не отобразиться. Ошибка будет типа: `SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break`, а вот где указана ошибка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот исходник: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать с этим? Только не надо говорить, что нужно лезть на сервер и там все ручками изменять, удалять эти пустые строки и т.д.. Подскажите как избавиться от этих пустых строк?

Comment: Не нужно выкладывать код картинкой, для этого существует сниппет, в котором Вы можете отобразить весь Ваш труд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let description = `Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне.

Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую...`;
```

измени кавычки

Comment: А если в тексте попадется кавычка `\``?

Answer (score 1):

Если текст формируется на сервере, заключите его в теги и извлеките с помощью javascript:

```js
var ptext = $('.ptext').text();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="ptext">тут какой-то текст даже с пробелами</p>
```

И дальше используйте эту переменную